# What's the way to run an Amazon Elastic Mapreduce job that depends on Numpy?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

The map portion of my Mapreduce job depends on Numpy. So, that means I need to have numpy installed as part of the bootstrap actions.

What I'm thinking of doing is building a custom Numpy package stored on S3 that is fetched and installed during the boostrap actions.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually, it looks like Numpy is installed by default on the mapreduce instances. The question still applies though, for other packages that aren't installed by default.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and maybe you've solved it by now, but you can use Amazon's script-runner jar to execute a script (on S3) that sets up whatever else you need. That's what Amazon uses to install Hive when you start up an EMR cluster with Hive support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy now comes installed on Amazon Elastic MapReduce instances, but if you want to use other modules, you can zip them up, distribute them to your workers with the DistributedCache (using "-cacheFile"), and then import them with Python's built-in "zipimport" module.

See: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2008/11/sending-files-to-remote-task-nodes-with-hadoop-mapreduce/